# Reverse shell with puTTY or poderosa?

Tags: ssh, putty, reverse-tunnel

Can I open a reverse shell with Podersa or puTTY? I would prefer Poderosa but I can't find the option to create a tunnel from my local machine port 9000 to my remote machine port 9000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure port forwarding in PuTTY. See `Connection > SSH > Tunnels`.
Some examples of usage: http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

Comment: Can I use cygwin to open a reverse shell from windows? I tried to connect to xdebug to no avail?

Comment: Probably yes if you have OpenSSH client installed on cygwin. So you can use `-R` and `-L` (I didn't test since I don't have a Windows machine but probably it'll work since it is the "same" OpenSSH from Linux distros, but built for Windows).

Comment: And to a virtual machine? I tried that too, to no avail?

Comment: If you can port forward to/from virtual machines? Yes.